# Serve HLS with raspap/lighttpd rather than nginx

Tags: nginx, lighttpd, hostapd, picamera

I currently serve audio/video from a raspberry pi using the [picam project](https://github.com/iizukanao/picam) along with `nginx` to stream it as an HLS (Http Live Streaming) stream (as detailed in the project page). Thus, in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` I add:

```
location /hls/ {
        root /run/shm;
    }
```

Then, I can access my stream (for example with VLC player) at `http://mypi.local/hls/index.m3u8`.

However, I no longer wish to rely on my internet box to stream. Indeed, I would like my client(s) to directly connect to the pi. Thus, I have recently tried [Raspap](https://github.com/RaspAP/raspap-webgui) to transform my raspberry pi to a hotspot.

However, as raspap seems to use `lighttpd` as its webserver, I am wondering how I can still stream my audio/video stream as it is currently done with `picam` and `nginx`.

Answer (score 1):

```
server.modules += ("mod_alias")
alias.url = ( "/hls/" => "/run/shm/" )
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: https://wiki.lighttpd.net/mod_alias